# How can I use a variable in find command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, system

```
 echo "Please, Type an existing title what you want to read: "
 read item_name
 item_name=${item_name,,}
 find . -type f -name '$item_name*'
```

How can I use the last line?

Comment: Use `"`, single quotes wont be expended to the variable's value

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to have the variable expanded:

```
find . -type f -name "$item_name*"
```

Comment: And how can i use cat command after this?

Comment: The `cat` command doesn't care if you ran `find`  before it, or at all. If you are trying to ask how to `cat` the found files, that's `find ... -exec cat {} +`. Going forward, please search before asking.